# "<=" parameter in function call to mean

Tags: r

I'm working through a [simple gamma example](https://rpubs.com/mpfoley73/459051).  The author uses an idiom for `mean` that I can't decipher:

```
alpha = 10
theta = 15 / 60
x = 3

mean(rgamma(n = 10000, shape = alpha, scale = theta) <= x)
## [1] 0.7527
```

the `<= x` parameter isn't documented in the R documentation, nor can I find any other examples of its use.

At first glance, it would seem like it would take the vector returned from `rgamma` and remove any value less than 3, but that's not it because then you'll have a mean of somewhere near 2.5, and that's no where near 0.7527.

What does that `<= x` at the end of the call to `mean` do?

Comment: Check how many values from rgamma are less than or equal to x (3) and take the mean of this bool vector (comprised of 0's and 1's) -> proportion.

Comment: Check ?`<=`. It's "inferior or equal to" sign

Comment: The `<=` will return a vector of TRUE/FALSE values. So you'll get TRUE if the values from `rgamma` are less than or equal to 3. If you take the `mean()` of a TRUE/FALSE column, the TRUEs become 1 and FALSEs become 0 so you essentially get the proportion of TRUE values. So the number is the proportion of values less than or equal to 3 (on a 0-1 scale), not the actual mean of those values. This is a very common idiom in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including that '<= 3' changes what you are taking the mean of.
In this case you are taking the mean of the Boolean vector 'is x <= 3?'.
Therefore, this would return the percentage of values in the vector that are <= 3.

For example:

```
> x = 1:10
> x<=5
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> mean(x<=5)
[1] 0.5
```

Hope this helps!